# factorial divided by a smaller factorial to the n power

Tags: factorial

This is the question I am asking:
Compute the greatest integer n for which (6!)^n is a factor of 60!.

This is an AMC style question as I am practicing for it.
I tried to find the amount of 6's in 60! and got 11, but it was incorrect.
Any help?

Comment: Finding the number of 6’s isn’t quite right. Try counting the  powers of primes instead: 2, 3, and 5.

Comment: @lulu- it is not clear which is the “worst”prime a priori. There are fewest 5s in 60!, but there are the most 2’s in 6!   It isn’t immediately obvious which prime will be the limiting factor (pun intended).

Comment: The product of any 6 consecutive numbers is divisible by $6!$. So the maximal power is at least 10. I believe it is exactly 10,

Comment: There are 14 5s in 60! And only one 5 in 6!.  So, just looking at 5’s, we have 60!/(6!)^14. We should also verify we have enough 2s an 3s in the numerator as well. Be careful, because 6! Has multiple 2s and 3s.

Comment: Thanks! I wish a could verify a comment but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count primes instead of the largest number. Usually, the largest prime has the least amount of numbers. So count the 5's. 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60. There are 12 5's and 2 more 5's from 25 and 50 so it is 12 + 2 = 14.